# Remote branch ahead of local branch; can't push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to push to heroku, but I recently dropped back a few commits as the production and local code were both flawed. Now I'm getting the error:

Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.

I don't want to pull from the remote, but rather push the code I have locally.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot. I went back and read the next line.

If it helps anyone in the future, the answer is to use --force:

```
git push heroku master -f
```

Comment: be careful, though. Using force is fine for a _secondary_ remote repo such as heroku, but I wouldn't use it with your main repo, e.g. Github, especially if you're on a team.

Comment: @FrankC.Eckert Oh! Of course not, no. I think there would be a LOT of unhappy people with me, if that was the case. Thank you for the important note!